# Same link returns everytime by using multiple excerpts

Tags: wordpress

On the main page in Wordpress I use multiple excerpts of different pages. The problem is though that it returns everytime the same excerpt link. It seems like the last link (of 3) on the page is used everytime.

The code (of course I changed the number of the id everytime ;-) :

```
<?php
$post_id = 35;  // post id
$queried_post = get_post($post_id); 
$my_excerpt = get_excerpt_by_id_long($queried_post); //$post_id is the post id of the desired post  

echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $queried_post ) . '" title="' . $queried_post->post_title . '">';
echo '<h3><strong>';
echo $queried_post->post_title;
echo '</strong></h3>';
echo '</a>';

echo $my_excerpt;
?>
```

This is in functions.php

```
function get_excerpt_by_id($post_id){

$the_post = get_post($post_id); //Gets post ID
$the_excerpt = $the_post->post_content; //Gets post_content to be used as a basis for the excerpt
$excerpt_length = 35; //Sets excerpt length by word count
$the_excerpt = strip_tags(strip_shortcodes($the_excerpt)); //Strips tags and images
$words = explode(' ', $the_excerpt, $excerpt_length + 1);
if(count($words) > $excerpt_length) :
array_pop($words);
array_push($words, '…');
$the_excerpt = implode(' ', $words);
endif;
$the_excerpt = '<p>' . $the_excerpt . '<a class="leesmeer" href="'.get_permalink($post_id).'">lees verder...</a></p>';

return $the_excerpt;
}
```

Comment: I found the solution: see answer below

Answer (score 0):

never mind, I found the solution: forgot to use the $post_id in the .get_permalink()...Edited the code in the above functions.php